# How do I get the page source of the html page using php codes?

Tags: php, mysql, html

How do I get the page source of the html page using php codes and then save all all of those codes into a database?

Is it possible?

Please help. Thanks.

Database is MySQL

Comment: Which HTML page? The one you're generating? One from an external HTTP server?

Comment: Really? This isn't a duplicate?

Answer (score 2):

The answer lies within [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) or [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php).

```
$string = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
echo $string;

// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();
// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
// grab URL and pass it to the browser
$string = curl_exec($ch);
echo $string;
// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
```

As far as storing in a database, presumably MySQL, you could use [mysql_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php).  I'd suggest using prepared statements but it seems as though that might be overwhelming at first glance for a PHP beginner.

Here's a very simple example of database connection and insertion:

```
$db = mysql_connect('DB_IP_OR_HOST','DB_USER','DB_PASS') or die("DB error");
mysql_select_db('YOUR_DB_NAME', $db);
$result = mysql_query('INSERT INTO MY_TABLE_NAME SET html = "' . mysql_real_escape_string($string) . '"');
mysql_close($db);
```

Answer (score 0):

If it lies on an external server, you can not view the PHP source, as it is a [server-side language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting). You can only view the client-side source (generally [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML)). If you would like to learn PHP to understand how the page was created, and make one similar, I suggest using [Tizag's PHP tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/) as they are very easy to understand.

However, otherwise you can use [fopen()](http://php.net/fopen) or [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/file_get_contents)